# Eigen:: cannot convert Block<Derived> to Ref<Derived> when number of cols is fixed

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, eigen, eigen3

I recently updated to recent Eigen version (3.3.90) and it looks like it broke stuff I though was working before (prior that I was using an Eigen version 3.2.10 shipped with the libigl library).

I would like to store the result of a block into a ref object that will be passed around and ultimately used to update the internals of the matrix form which the block was extracted.

A minimal example which does not compile anymore:

```cxx
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  typedef Eigen::Matrix<bool, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> Mtype;
  typedef Eigen::Block<Mtype> Btype;
  typedef Eigen::Ref<Mtype> Rtype;
  Mtype m(2, 1);
  Btype bm = m.block(0, 0, 1, 1);
  Rtype rm = m; // OK
  Rtype rbm = bm; // Visual studio 2017 error C2440: 'initialisation' : impossible conversion
}
```

Note that the const version does work, I think this is due to the specialization of Ref for const which recreates a temporary copy:

```cxx
typedef Eigen::Ref<const Mtype> CRtype;
CRtype crbm = bm; // OK
```

Similarly using a Matrix type with *both* number of rows and cols *Dynamic*, also compiles:

```cxx
typedef Eigen::Matrix<bool, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> Mtype;
typedef Eigen::Block<Mtype> Btype;
typedef Eigen::Ref<Mtype> Rtype;
Mtype m(2, 1);
Btype bm = m.block(0, 0, 1, 1);
Rtype rbm = bm;
```

Any clues?

Thanks a lot!

Best regards,

Jerome

Comment: Sorry, It was in french : ) anyway it said the conversion from Btype to Rtype was impossible. Switching to an oldest Eigen version did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eigen version 3.3.90 is a development branch and things there may be broken. Using the latest stable release (3.3.7) solves this issue. That being said, you can file a bug report with the Eigen devs to ensure that this is noticed (although, by the time you do, they'll likely have seen this post).

Comment: That's the opposite: it's a bug in Eigen 3.2 and 3.3 that is fixed in the devel branch ;)

Comment: @ggael Even better. +1

Comment: Using 3.3.7 fixes the problem indeed, I am still confused though: the fix was rolled out in 3.3.7 but not in 3.3.90?

Comment: The story is more complicated: there was an issue with the handling of 0-sized blocks in older Eigen versions. Fixing this corner-case issue in the devel branch leveraged the issue you hit.

Answer (score 2):

My previous answer was too fast in its conclusion. This is now fixed: https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/commits/cacb7b4ace39/

Nonetheless, it's still better to keep compile-time vector as compile-time vectors. This information is lost by `Block<VectorXd>` (and `m.block(0, 0, 1, 0)`) because it  might have 1 or 0 column at runtime, e.g.:

```
Block<VectorXd> bm = m.block(0, 0, 1, 0);
```

is perfectly fine. So in your case, I would still recommend to preserve this information, e.g.:

```
auto bm = m.segment(0,1);
auto bm = m.block(0,0,1,fix<1>);       // fix is new in Eigen 3.4
auto bm = m.block<Dynamic,1>(0,0,1,1); // <3.4 version of the above cleaner line
```

This is a typical situation where you should really use `auto`. You can also directly initialize the Ref, e.g.:

```
Ref<MType> rm = m.segment(0,1);
```

Comment: Totally agree that `m.segment(0,1)` is better here, But I'm not sure: Should `Ref<VectorXd>` probably also accept expressions which are vectors at runtime (with proper assertions, of course)? E.g., `Ref<MatrixX2d>` does not require the second dimension to be fixed at compile time.

Comment: Yes you're right. This would be consistent with other fixed-size matrices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I wonder why should I switch to double instead of bool? I am accepting @avi-ginsburg answer because currently using 3.3.7 is a good fix, but I am all ears about your Eigen's guru advice. thx.

Comment: No no, I switched to double simply to use the `VectorXd` typedef which more explicitly convey the idea of a compile-time vector than your `MType`.